# Yii2 сохранить время, когда пользователь выполнил logout

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, yii2

**Hello World!**

Я создал в базу данных  last_activity чтобы узнать когда полбзователь выполнил login,как изменить этот значения чтобы было 0000-00-00 00:00:00 когда пользователь выполнит (выйти) logout.

```
 public function actionLogout()
    {

        $event = $this->getUserEvent(\Yii::$app->user->identity);
      /*  $account = $this->finder->findAccount()->byClient($client)->one();
        $account->user->updateAttributes(['last_activity' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00']);*/
        $this->trigger(self::EVENT_BEFORE_LOGOUT, $event);

       $logout = \Yii::$app->getUser()->logout();
       /* if ($logout){
            $module = \Yii::$app->getModule('user');
            $module->updateAttributes(['last_activity'=>'0000-00-00 00:00:00']);
        }*/
        $this->trigger(self::EVENT_AFTER_LOGOUT, $event);
      //  \Yii::$app->user->updateAttributes(['last_activity' => 0]);
      //  User::deleteLast();
    //    \Yii::$app->user->updateAttributes(['last_activity' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00']);
       //  $this->updateAttributes(['last_activity' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00']);
       // $this->user->updateAttributes(['last_activity' => null]);
       // return Yii::$app->user->updateAttributes(['last_ip'=> 1]);
          return $this->redirect(site/index);
    }
```

***View cabinet-panel.php***

```
  <?php
        echo Menu::widget([
            'items' => [
               ////
                [
                    'label' => Yii::t('main', "Logout"),
                    'url' => null,
                    'options' => ['class' => 'li-logout'],
                    'template' => '<a id="link-logout">{label}</a>'
                ],
            ],
            'options' => [
                'class' => 'nav nav-pills nav-stacked'
            ],
            'activeCssClass' => 'active',
            'route' => Yii::$app->request->url,
            'activateItems' => true,
        ]);
        ?>
```

***common.js***
здесь function,когда пользователь нажимает на

```
function logout() {

    $(document).on('click', '#link-logout', function () {
        $.post(getLang() + '/user/security/logout/');
    });
   /*  $.ajax({
        url: getLang() + 'user/security/logout',
        type: 'POST',
        data : {
            'last_activity' : '000000000000000'
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            data['user']['last_activity'] = 'last_activity'
        }
    }) */
}

logout();
```

Comment: Кажется в этом нет особого смысла, потому что не все пользователи нажимают выход.

Comment: как можно сделать по другому я хочу это использовать чтобы показать если пользователь в сети или нет. Если у вас другие мнение скажите пожалуйста @fedornabilkin

Comment: С каждым запросм обновлять пользователю поле last_activity текущим временем. Потом отнимать эти данные от текущего времени и, если прошло 5 минут, например, то считать, что пользователь покинул сайт.

Comment: простите пожалуйтса я просто не давно ровно 4 месяца назад начил заниматься. То есть как я понял на каждый function обновлять эту поле ?

Comment: Каждый запрос, который приходит на сервер обработать, если юзер авторизован, то обновить поле. Можно в компонент response добавить, например.

Answer (score 0):

**Ответ исходя из обсуждений в комментариях**

В конфиге добавить вызов метода, а в методе обновлять необходимое поле для текущего юзера.

```
'components' => [
'response' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\Response',
    'on beforeSend' => function ($event) {
            UserHelper::setLastActivity();
        }
    },
],
```

Соответственно создать класс и метод. Можно метод создать в классе User, тогда проще получить текущего пользователя.